# half mini/mini PCIe to PCIe Adapter

Tags: wifi, pcie, network-adapter, durability

I'm looking for a 1x PCIe Adapter supporting half mini and mini PCIe wireless network card

- Quality components
- Transparent (No additional drivers needed etc)
- 3 antenna connector preferred (2 minimum)
- Able to use the full speed of a PCIe slot
- Compatible with all existing 802.11 protocols + Bluetooth

Answer (score 1):

There really aren't all that many options for this out there.  Newegg has one: the [Silverstone ECWA2-Lite](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815256026).  It uses simple pass-through connectors to your computer's PCIe slot and internal USB header, so it runs at full speed, needs no additional drivers, and should be compatible with any mini-PCIe card.  It's only got two antennas, though.

Comment: Also, the quality will be about the same from most adapters like this.  Since there isn't much demand, nearly all the distributors use the same OEMs.